# Triangle, incenter and perpendicular line

Tags: euclidean-geometry

For the triangle $ABC$, let $I$ the incenter and $I_A$ the A-excenter. If $L$ the midpoint of arc $BC$, we can show that $L$ is the center of a circle through $I, I_A, B, C.$ Also, if the incircle touches $AB, AC$ at $P, Q$ and $BI, CI$ intersect with $PQ$ at $K, L$ we may show that circumcircle of $ILK$ is tangent to incircle of $ABC$ if and only if $AB+AC=3BC.$ My problem is that if the line through $I$ is perpendicular to $BI$ and meets $AC$ at $X,$ while the line through $I$ perpendicular to $CI$ meets $AB$ at $Y$ and $AB+AC=3BC$, I stuck to show that $X, I_A, Y$ are collinear

Comment: I stuck to show that $X, I_A, Y$ ...  ?

Comment: 1) Which circle contains arc BC? 2) It is not possible to have a circle passing through I, I(A), B, C.

Comment: http://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Fact5/Fact5.pdf

Comment: The diagram clarifies my question #2. Referring to my question #1, you cannot just post a diagram without refining your problem statement. Also, please use the "@..." to address  the person you are responding to. Without that, no one will notice your response unless he/she re-visits this post.

Comment: Please fix once for all times the statement of one and only one problem, having careful definitions of all introduced objects. Please give a picture, and *then* show the own attempts to solve the problem. It is now hard to figure out where is the statement, where it stops, what it claims, and which is your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to extract a question from the OP. So i suppose the question is solved by the following result:

> Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with sides $a,b,c$. Let $p=(a+b+c)/2$ be its half-perimeter. We assume
>   $$
> 3a=b+c\ .
> $$
>   Let $I$ and $I_A$ be the incenter and the $A$-excenter of $\Delta ABC$. Let $P\in AB$, $Q\in AC$, $R\in BC$ be the touching points of the inscribed circle $(I)$ (centered in $I$).
>
> - Then $AP=AQ=p-a=BC$.
>
> Let $W$ be the mid point of $AI$.
>
> Let $RI$ further intersect the circle $(I)$ in a point $U$ (with $U\ne R$). Parallel and equal to the segment $IR$, we construct in the half plane delimited by $BC$, which does not contain $I,A$, the segments $BB^*$, and $CC^*$. These segments are in particular perpendicular on $BC$, and the quadrilaterals $UIB^*B$, $IRB^*B$; $UIC^*C$, $IRC^*C$ are parallelograms. Let now $V$ be the second point on the circumcircle $(ABC)$, where the angle bisector from $A$ intersects this circle. ($V\ne A$.) It is characterized by
>   $$\widehat{VBC}=\widehat{VCB}=\frac 12\hat A\ ,$$ and that is located on the angle bisector $AII_A$, and its intersection with the side bisector of $BC$ (through $R'$, the mid point of $BC$).
>
> - Show that the triangles $\Delta AIP$,  $\Delta AIQ$,  $\Delta BC^*C$,  $\Delta CB^*B$ are congruent.
> - Show that $VCAB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Show that $BCC^*B^*$ is a rectangle, and its center $BC^*\cap B^*C$ is $V$. In particular, the hexagon $ICC^*I_AB^*B$ is cyclic, the center of the circle $(ICC^*I_AB^*B)$ coincides with $V$, and we have moreover its radius:
>     $$
>   VI=VB=VB^*=VI_A=VC^*=VC=\frac 12BC^*=\frac 12B^*C=\frac 12AI=AW=WI\ .
>   $$
>
> [image: stackexchange geometry problem 3326742 incircle tangent to smaller circle with half radius]
>
> We define two points $K,L$ after defining $U$ as follows. Consider the triangle $UBC$. Its heights are $UR$, and $BK,CL$, thus defining $K\in UC$, $L\in UB$.
>
> - Show that $I$ is the orhtocenter of $UBC$, 
>     $$I=UR\cap BK\cap CL\ .
>   $$
> - Show that $IKUL$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. The segment $UI$ is a diameter of the circle $(IKUL)$.
> - Show that $P,L,K,Q$ are colinear.
>
> The parallel through $I$ to the line $ULB$ intersects $AB$ in a point denoted by $Y$.
>
> The parallel through $I$ to the line $UKC$ intersects $AC$ in a point denoted by $X$.
>
> ---
>
> - Show that $X,I_A,Y$ are colinear.

---

**Proof:**

- The relation $AP=AQ=p-a$ holds in a general triangle. In our case, we have further $p-a=(a+b+c)/2-a=(a+3a)/2-a=2a-a=a=BC$.
- The triangles $\Delta AIP$,  $\Delta AIQ$,  $\Delta BC^*C$,  $\Delta CB^*B$ are congruent, because they have a right angle in $P$, $Q$, $C$, and respectively $B$, and they have equal catetes, $a=AP=AQ=BC$, and $IP=IQ=IR=BB^*=CC^*$. In particular, the hypotenuses are correspondingly equal, and the other angles, too:
  $$ 
  \begin{aligned}
  &AI = BC^*=B^*C\ ,\\
  &\widehat{C^*BC}=\widehat{B^*CB}=\frac 12\hat A 
  \ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  By construction, $BB^*$, $CC^*$ are parallel, equal, and build right angles with $BC$. So $BCC^*B^*$ rectangle. The intersection of the diagonals satisfies the above property that determines $V$, $\widehat{C^*BC}=\widehat{B^*CB}=\frac 12\hat A $, so this intersection is on the circle $(ABC)$, and it is the mid point of the arc $\overset \frown{BC}$, so it is $V$.
  The quadrilateral $IBI_AC$ is also cyclic, two opposite right angles, and $II_A$ is a diameter of the circle 
  $(IBI_AC)$. Its mid point is $V$, the second intersection point of $AII_A$ with the circle $(ABC)$, so the two circles $(IBI_AC)$ and $(BCC^*B^*)$ coincide, and we have the long equality of segments:
  $$
  AW=WI=IV=VB=VC=VB^*=VC^*=VI_A\ .
  $$
- Let us now show the properties related to $U$. By construction, the segment $UI$ is parallel and equal to $BB^*$ and $CC^*$. So $UBB^*I$ is a parallelogram. So 
  $$
  \widehat{BUR}=
  \widehat{BUI}=
  \widehat{BB^*I}=
  \widehat{BCI}\ .
  $$
  The line $CI$ is thus perpendicular on $BU$. Similarly $BI\perp CU$. So $I$ is the orthocenter in $UBC$, and $B,I,K$ are colinear, and $C,I,L$ are colinear.
- Let us show that $P,Q,K,L$ are colinear. For this, we use an inversion $\#$ with center $I$ and power $-IP^2=-IQ^2=-IR^2$, this argument is simplest from my point of view, a picture for this argument would be:
  [image: Colinearity of four points in a special configuration, proof by inversion] 
  The point $P$ is transformed in its opposite $P^{\#}$ w.r.t. the center of inversion $I$, so $PP^{\#}$ is a diameter in $(I)$.
  The point $Q$ is transformed in its opposite $Q^{\#}$, so $QQ^{\#}$ is a diameter in $(I)$.
  The point $K$ is transformed in $K^{\#}=B$. (Because the triangles $\Delta IKU$, $\Delta IRB$ are similar, so $IK\cdot IB=IU\cdot IR=-IR^2$.) Similarly, $L$ is transformed in $L^{\#}=C$. To show that $P,Q,K,L$ are colinear, we show equivalently that the transformed points $P^{\#}$, $Q^{\#}$, $B=K^{\#}$, $C=L^{\#}$  are on a circle through $I$. (This is of course the circle $(IBC)$, and we already have a lot of points on it, i wanted two more, this is the reason for this approach.)
  It is enough to show $P^{\#}$ on the circle $(IBC)$. We show this by comparison of the angles in $P^{\#}$ and $I$ in the quadrilateral $IP^{\#}CB$. A first progress in this direction is given by the remark that $U,K,P^{\#},C$ are colinear. (Because their transformed points $R,B,P,L$ are on a circle through $I$, yes, it is a circle with diameter $BI$.) So $P^{\#}$ is the symmetric of $U$ w.r.t. $K$. We then compute:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}  
  \widehat{BP^{\#}C}
  &=
  \pi-\widehat{BP^{\#}U}\\
  &=
  \pi-\widehat{BUP^{\#}}\\
  &=
  \pi-\widehat{LUK}\\
  &=
  \widehat{LIK}\\
  &=
  \widehat{BIC}\ .
  \end{aligned}  
  $$
  The comparison shows we have to equal angles in $P^{\#}$ and $I$ in the quadrilateral $IP^{\#}CB$, so it is cyclic, this is exactly what we wanted. Same game for $Q^{\#}$.

---

- We finally attack the question from the OP.

**Let us show the colinearity of $X,Y,I_A$.** (I could not find a simple Desargue or Pappus argument, mainly because the points $X,Y$ are on lines defined by too few "distinguished points". So the argument is inversion again. So i inserted the above "short prelude", same thematical idea.) We denote by $X^{\#}$, $Y^{\#}$, $I_A^{\#}$ the points obtained from $X,Y,I_A$ by the same inversion $\#$.

Firstly, $I_A^{\#}$ is the point on $II_A$ at the intersection with $PQ$ because of
$$
II_A^{\#}\cdot IA = IP^2\ .
$$
Secondly, the point $Y^{\#}$ is on $IB^*$, and also on the circle which is the image by inversion of the line $APB$. The point $A^{\#}$ is the intersection of $IA$ with $P^{\#}Q^{\#}$. It is also the symmetrical point of $I_A^{\#}$ w.r.t. $I$. The points $P,Q$ have already discussed inverses, $P^{\#}$, $Q^{\#}$, so that  $PP^{\#}$, and $QQ^{\#}$ are diameters. Shortly, $Y^{\#}$ is the point on the circle with diameter $IP^{\#}$ which is the second intersection point with the line perpendicular on $IL$ in $I$.

The point $X^{\#}$ is located similarly, it is the point on the circle with diameter $IQ^{\#}$ which is the second intersection point with the line perpendicular on $IK$ in $I$.

*We want to show that the points $I, X^{\#}, Y^{\#},I_A^{\#}$ are on a circle.*

[image: Proof by inversion of a colinearity of points.]

We construct the point $Z$ as the intersection
$Q^{\#}X^{\#}\cap P{\#}Y{\#}$.

Observe that $Q^{\#}X^{\#}\|IK$, both lines being perpendicular on $X^{\#}IC^*$.
So $Q^{\#}X^{\#}Z\perp UP^{\#}$, because $IK\perp UP^{\#}$.
Similarly $P^{\#}Y^{\#}Z\perp UQ^{\#}$.

So $Z$ is the orthocenter in the triangle $\Delta UQ^{\#}P^{\#}$.

So $UZ\perp Q^{\#}P^{\#}$.

So $UZ\perp PLKQ$. We want to show that $Z$ is on this last line. 
For this observe that $\Delta UPQ\equiv \Delta ZQ^{\#}P^{\#}$, because the sides are parallel, and one corresponding side has the same length,
$PQ\equiv Q^{\#}P^{\#}$. So $UPQ^{\#}Z$ and $UQP^{\#}Z$ are parallelograms.
So $UZ=PQ^{\#}=QP^{\#}$. But $PLKQ$ is mid line in $\Delta UQ^{\#}Q^{\#}$, so the distance from $U$ to $PLKQ$ is the same as the distance $PQ^{\#}=QP^{\#}$
between the parallels $PQ\| Q^{\#}P^{\#}$. So $Z$ is on the mid line.

From $II_A^{\#}A\perp PLKQ$ we immediately conclude:

*The points $X^{\#}$, $Y^{\#}$, $I_A^{\#}$, lie on the circle
with diameter $IZ$.*

$\square$